# MySQL: Most Efficient Way To AND Multiple Selections?

Tags: mysql

If I have the following data, what would be the most efficient query to get the result of gameId 1411051547 (listed below)? Also, what type of query would this be called? I'm learning MySQL and I wasn't sure what to search for when trying to learn about these types of queries.

Input data:

```
championId IN (19, 23, 40) AND win=True
AND
championId IN (7, 18) AND win=False
```

Here is how the data is setup in the database:

```
mysql> SELECT gameId,championId,win from match_up WHERE gameId=1411051547;
+------------+------------+-----+
| gameId     | championId | win |
+------------+------------+-----+
| 1411051547 |          7 |   0 |
| 1411051547 |         18 |   0 |
| 1411051547 |         19 |   1 |
| 1411051547 |         23 |   1 |
| 1411051547 |         31 |   0 |
| 1411051547 |         40 |   1 |
| 1411051547 |         45 |   1 |
| 1411051547 |         77 |   0 |
| 1411051547 |        236 |   1 |
| 1411051547 |        412 |   0 |
+------------+------------+-----+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: These predicates will result in an empty set. There are no rows that satisfy this set of conditions. (If championId = 19, then `championId IN (7, 18)` will return FALSE, so the entire predicate will be FALSE.) I think you're wanting an `OR` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT gameId
from match_up 
group by gameId
having sum(championId IN (19, 23, 40) AND win = 1) = 3
and sum(championId IN (7, 18) AND win = 0) = 2
```

You need to group by the `gameId` to analyze the data of each group since you want to check several records and not just one.

`having` is the  `where` clause of a group. In that you can use aggregaret functions like `sum()`  to check for conditions of the whole group and not just for a single record.

Comment: Thanks, this returned the desired result. I removed the WHERE gameId = 1411051547 from your statement because the input data I'm using does not include the gameId. This still returned the desired result. Thanks for the statement AND the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for an OR clause

```
SELECT gameId,championId,win from match_up 
WHERE gameId=1411051547 AND
(
    (championId IN (19, 23, 40) AND win=True)
    OR
    (championId IN (7, 18) AND win=False)
)
```

depending on the definition of the `win` field, it might be safer to use 1 instead of True, and 0 instead of false.

Comment: I should have clarified, the Input data does not include gameId. If I remove gameId=1411051547 from your statement it returns results I am not looking for.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with an example of what kind of result are you expecting? Is it something like "get all the gameIds in which users 19,23 and 40 have won and users 7 and 18 have lost?"

Answer (score 0):

without gameId in the query, and using the OR suggested by amenadiel:

```
select distinct gameId from match_up WHERE (
  (championId IN (19, 23, 40) AND win=True)
  OR
  (championId IN (7, 18) AND win=False)
);
```

Here's an [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ee956/2)